# Is my query correct when I set primary key for 3 columns in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

1. In my case, I have only **1 candidate may go with 1 job at the time** so they are must be 2 primary key.
2. Then, a column is as `JobApplicationId` use for the table `CandidateDetail` as a foreign key.

Is that correct when I decide to set these 3 columns above as primary key or there are other ways to address my problem here?

```
CREATE TABLE Candidate(
CandidateId int identity primary key,
FullName nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Job(
JobId int identity primary key,
JobTitle nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE JobApplication(
JobApplicationId int identity,
JobId int,
CandidateId int,
CreatedDate datetime,
primary key(JobApplicationId, JobId, CandidateId)
)

CREATE TABLE CandidateDetail(
CandidateDetailId int identity primary key,
JobApplicationId int,
[Description] nvarchar(300)
)

ALTER TABLE JobApplication ADD CONSTRAINT fk_JobApplication_Job FOREIGN KEY (JobId) REFERENCES Job(JobId)
ALTER TABLE JobApplication ADD CONSTRAINT fk_JobApplication_Candidate FOREIGN KEY (CandidateId) REFERENCES Candidate(CandidateId)
ALTER TABLE CandidateDetail ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CandidateDetail_JobApplication FOREIGN KEY (JobApplicationId) REFERENCES JobApplication(JobApplicationId)
```

Comment: So every time a person candidates for a job a new candidate number is issued. Right? But if so, then "candidate" means the same as "application". If not so, then a candidate number gets re-used. Which is correct? Please clarify.

Comment: Please do not take lots of attention on the name of the table, it can be anything. What I mean here is how I can solve the problem when I insert JobId=1 and CandidateId=1 and then I insert these again. It should give an error as 1 Candidate can apply for 1 only Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a primary key with three columns you could just have JobApplicationId as the primary key and a unique constraint on JobId, CandidateId.

Otherwise, two rows with JobApplicationId=1, JobId=1, CandidateId=1 and JobApplicationId=2, JobId=1, CandidateId=1 would still be valid in terms of your current primary key approach, but would be invalid in terms of the business case.

Comment: So if I insert twice JobId=1 and CandidateId=1, it is still valid. However, in my case that is not possible. That means that 1 Candidate cannot apply for a Job twice.

Comment: I just demonstrated an example where your primary key is still valid, including unwanted data. Therefore, I recommended the unique constraint to prevent such a scenario. This will also make the composite primary obsolete and you can use JobApplicationId as the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

From both a performance and usability perspective, a compound primary key can be a hassle and can create performance issues.  Personally, I would choose `JobApplicationId` as the primary key (because this is an identity column and will be unique for each record).  Then, if you need to constrain the table so that JobId and CandidateId are always unique (not allowing more than 1 record for any given candidate and the job they've applied for) then I would use a compound Unique Constraint.

However, I would suggest that you evaluate those requirements more closely because what if a candidate applies for the same position in a different time frame?  It might stand to reason that having the same candidate applied to the same job more than once in that table might be valid data.